# How to load a csv file to jupyter notebook using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load the CSV to my jupyter notebook.

my file path in jupyter notebook: Data/country_vaccinations.csv

My Os:- Windows 10

and I am getting this error!!!
[image: click here for my code and corresponding error]

would any of you be kind enough to help me with this issue, please?

Comment: What is the output when you run: `import os, os.listdir('Data')` (in separate lines)

Comment: give the absoulute path or make sure the csv in the samepath as that of notebook

Comment: @Ajay the CSV is exactly in the same path as that of the notebook. I have created a folder named Data in jupyter and the file is in that folder.

Comment: @AnirbanSaha Its file not found error. But I have created the folder called Data in jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is in Data subfolder, change 'Data/'  to `'Data\\'`.

This should do the job.

Comment: it is in different folder and actually, pandas can read the CSV file.

Comment: Changed the answer above

Comment: the jupyter file is in one folder and data file is in another folder. and yes, i tried the above technique. But it did not help.

Comment: See again above. There was a display issue with my answer. You should change with two slashes

Comment: @ gtomer, still the issue persists.

Comment: Then you either misspelled the file name or the path. Python cannot find the file

Answer (score 0):

I gave my local path instead of jupyter notebook path and it worked.